# How to culculate the corrcoef between df.Series and df.Series.shift(1) with numpy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, correlation, pearson-correlation

I'm dealing with TSA, and need to know the corrcoef between `df.Series` and `df.Series.shift(1)` . `df.corr()` is helpful as showed below:

(1) `df.DataFrame.corr()`

```py
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/daily-min-temperatures.csv',
                 index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
values = pd.DataFrame(df.values)
dataframe = pd.concat([values.shift(1), values], axis=1)
dataframe.columns = ['col1', 'col2']

print(dataframe.corr())
"""
         col1     col2
col1  1.00000  0.77487
col2  0.77487  1.00000
"""
```

The questions is i don't know how to do it with `numpy.corrcoef`
or `scipy.stats.stats.pearsonr`, thx in advance for any help!

(2) `numpy` and `scipy.stats.stats.pearsonr` is applied this way

```
a = dataframe['col1']
b = dataframe['col2']
print(np.corrcoef(a, b))
"""
[[nan nan]
 [nan  1.]]
"""

print(scipy.stats.stats.pearsonr(a, b))
"""
ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs
"""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gist of the issue is that `DataFrame.corr` automatically excluded N/A values for you while numpy and scipy offer no such luxury. The first value in `col2` in N/A because it was created from a `shift`.

Exclude that first value and you are good to go:

```
>>> a = df.iloc[1:, 0]
>>> b = df.iloc[1:, 1]

>>> np.corrcoef(a,b)
array([[1.        , 0.77487022],
       [0.77487022, 1.        ]])

>> scipy.stats.stats.pearsonr(a,b)
(0.7748702165384456, 0.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The first row of `df.shift(1)` will be NaN because there's no element before it. You need to remove that row when calculating them

```
>>> scipy.stats.stats.pearsonr(df.values.flatten()[1:],
                               df.shift(1).values.flatten()[1:])
(0.7748702165384456, 0.0)

>>> np.corrcoef(df.values.flatten()[1:],
                df.shift(1).values.flatten()[1:])
array([[1.        , 0.77487022],
       [0.77487022, 1.        ]])
```

Comment: You offered another way to culculate the corrcoef. thx xcmkz!

Answer (score 1):

You can't compute it because `shift` makes one value `nan`. You can just backfill this missing value. It will introduce a tiny amount of bias.

```
print(np.corrcoef(a.bfill(), b))
```

```
[[1.        0.7752074]
 [0.7752074 1.       ]]
```

Or, calculate the coefficient from the 2nd value on to avoid this shortcoming:

```
print(np.corrcoef(a[1:], b[1:]))
```

```
[[1.         0.77487022]
 [0.77487022 1.        ]]
```

`bfill` and `ffill` (back fill and forward fill) are ways to propagate nearby values to a missing value (`None` or `NaN`). In other words, taking the next value, or the preceding value.

```
pd.DataFrame([list('ab'), list('def')])
```

```
   0  1     2
0  a  b  None
1  d  e     f
```

Now we'll "back fill" this value with the next value:

```
pd.DataFrame([list('ab'), list('def')]).bfill()
```

```
   0  1  2
0  a  b  f
1  d  e  f
```

You can back fill, forward fill, and from left and right or up and down.

Comment: It's helpful and another way to deal with it. Thx to Nicolas Gervais! In the other hand, could you pls give more info about `a.bfill()` ? first time I know it.

Comment: of course! i put more info in the answer. glad i could help